# Is there any normal subgroup of $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Normal subgroups of $S_N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44301/normal-subgroups-of-s-n)

I wonder if there is any normal proper subgroup of $S_n$?

If yes, give an example.

Comment: hint: the most famous non-trivial subgroup of $S_n$ is normal.

Comment: The alternating group $A_n$ has index $2$ in $S_n$, and index $2$ subgroups are always normal...

Comment: Sure $H=\{e\}$.

Comment: I thought of posting an answer, but Henry Horton's comment covers it.

Comment: @Maths Lover: You should have asked for atleast 'non-trivial' subgroup

Comment: @HenryT.Horton , you are right !! 

thanks !

Comment: @Avatar , proper means non-trivial !

Comment: @MathsLover: usually it's not.

Comment: @Avatar , how ? 
what i know that proper subgroup means nontrivial subgroup , can you explain more ?

Comment: @Avatar: usually, it means not entire group nor trivial subgroup (at least across 3 books I've read). Could have been defined differently in your source, obviously.

Comment: A common convention is that a proper subgroup of $G$ is a subgroup $H \neq G$, while a non-trivial subgroup of $G$ is a subgroup $H \neq \{ e \}$.  But I am sure there are different conventions floating about, and most mathematicians are a bit cavalier about these issues since it's usually (?) clear from context what is meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly, yes.

- The [*alternating group*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) $\,A_n \leq S_n\,$ is a *normal subgroup* of $\,S_n\,$, since its index $\,[S_n : A_n] = 2$,
- and [*all subgroups of index $\,2\,$ are normal*](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Index_2_is_Normal). (The last link is to a proof of this fact.)
- Indeed, for all $S_n \;\text{with }\,n\geq 5,\,$ $A_n\,$ is the *ONLY* normal (non-trivial) subgroup of $\,S_n$.

Comment: thanks . your answer is excellent :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: :D i asked a question about group actions and permuations groups form serval minutes , plz check it and help if you can :) , thanx again .